# Using data from another sheet in a formula with sheet name in formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested-if

I'm writing a finance spreadsheet with google sheets and it works fine, except that I have to manually rewrite every entry in the formula to use the correct sheet. Is there a way to insert a variable in the following formula to make it read the sheet name from another cell?

```
=abs(SUMIFS('Feb21'!$I:$I;'Feb21'!$L:$L;D$2))
```

In the above formula, Feb21 is the sheet name that I'd like to be referenced by another cell.
I already tried indirect, but it just tells me that there's an error in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `INDIRECT`:

```
=ABS(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(A1&"!I:I"); INDIRECT(A1&"!L:L"); D$2))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!